# Can the trebuchet launcher be installed on the stock ROM?

Tags: launcher, trebuchet

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4
Android: 4.2.2

Can the trebuchet launcher be installed on the stock ROM?

I can't find the app on Google Play. Where could I get this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you prefer Trebuchet to launchers that aren't created for CM? There are a bunch of them.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 Just for testing purposes. I already have Nova Premium installed.

Comment: Trebuchet is a modified version of ICS(upgraded to JB) AOSP launcher with CyanogenMod tweaks, might work/might not as it could be relying on CM specific settings. Try it out and let us know! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can (with varying degrees of success)! I'm running it on my Prestigio 3350DUO (Android 4.2.2). But there is a problem with crashing on certain preferences (NumberPicker), so I cannot change number of screens or default screen, as well as number of docker icons/pages. Besides that, it works great - it's fast and stable and looks cool!